# Unicode errors with file upload

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am writing a [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) app to monitor a file system and post files (with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) on creation and modification events to a url.

I have inherited a wonky Django app that sorta/kinda worked when tested on linux and OSX (utf8 encoded files).

Now I am deploying to Windows and seeing UnicodeDecodeErrors:

The first suspect is this line (line 88)  in a view:

```
files = [io.StringIO(unicode(request.body))]
```

Which managed to hold things together until I started posting from a windows test box:

```
def do_stuff(self, fname, mimetype):
    auth = self.get_auth()
    index_url = self.get_index_url()
    files = {
        "file": (fname, open(fname, 'rb'), mimetype, {'Expires': '0'})
   }
    resp = requests.post(
        index_url, auth=auth, files=files, headers={'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream"}
    )
```

If I am reading the docs on requests correctly, that a way to post a file to an api endpoint.  But I get UnicodeDecodeErrors from windows and clean file uploads from linux.

Any insight is appreciated.

The Traceback is:

```
[ERROR] {2016-01-29 17:16:13,612 base.handle_uncaught_exception()@base.py:224 56331 4557533184}:
Internal Server Error: /_search/default/test_wd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "apps/utils/views.py", line 47, in dispatch
    return super(CSRFExemptMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "apps/needle/views/base.py", line 71, in dispatch
    rv = super(RestApiView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "apps/needle/views/base.py", line 234, in dispatch
    return super(BaseNeedleView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/opencrowd/pyvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "apps/needle/views/index_views.py", line 88, in post
    files = [io.StringIO(unicode(request.body))]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 254: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you at least post the full tracebck of the error?

Comment: maybe `encode()` to UTF-8 manually because it tries to encode to ASCII.